# $ \frac{dy}{dx} = \tan(a) $ ; the derivative of a circle at a point (tangent) with respect to $y$ and $x$

Tags: calculus, geometry

warm up derivative: slope of the tangent line for the top half of a circle.

I found that $$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} \left( x^2 + y^2 = 1 \right) \\ \rightarrow \dfrac{dy}{dx} = -\dfrac{x}{y} $$

please excuse the excessive amount of edits, and I apologize to those I confused.

edit:
I am only looking for the equation for the top half of the circle.
The tangent line goes from some point on the circle to the x-axis.

edit2:
I am looking for the relationship of the slope of the tangent line to the angle $\alpha$ the tangent line makes with the $x$-axis.

This is what I'm trying to prove for arbitrary values of $x$ and $y$:

$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \tan(\alpha) $

Attempted solution:

$tan(\alpha)= \frac{y}{x}  $

The tangent line to a circle has slope $ \frac{dy}{dx}$

The line equation for when the tangent line hits the x-axis is y = $ \frac{dy}{dx}$x + 0

$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x}$

$tan(\alpha) = \frac{dy}{dx}$

can anyone confirm this?

Comment: The top half of the circle with centre the origin and radius $1$ has equation $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. The bottom half has equation $y=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: That derivative is not only correct for the top half of the circle, but all points on the circle where $y\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for adding more information, RohanLatinSindhi. I edited the problem again to clarify what $\alpha$ means, and you should note that you can't have arbitrary values of all three of $x, y$, and $\alpha$, since $\alpha$ depends on the other two. It is true that $\tan \alpha$ is the slope of the tangent line; are you really looking for a solution using calculus? It is much easier to just draw a diagram and use trigonometry, I'd say.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the equation $(y-0)=-x/y(x-5)$, where
$-x/y$ represents the partial derivatives w.r.t $x$ and w.r.t. $y$
This equation results in the points on the circle where the lines from the (0,5) will be tangent.
Complete the equations of the tangents using the point slope formula.

Answer (score 0):

When $p=(x,y)$ lies on the circle  $x^2+y^2=1$ and $y\ne 0,$ the slope of the line $L_1 $ thru $p$ and the origin is $y/x.$ The tangent-line $ L_2$ at $p,$ to the circle, is perpendicular to $L_1$, so its slope is $-x/y.$ So $dx/dy=-x/y$...... The slope of a line $L,$ not perpendicular to the $x$-axis, is $\tan A_L$ where $A_L$ is the angle  that $L$ makes with the $x$-axis, measured counter-clockwise from the $x$-axis.   A little geometry shows that if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are any two perpendicular lines, and if neither is perpendicular to the $x$-axis, then $\tan A_{L_2}=-\cot A_{L_1}=-1/\tan A_{L_1}.$

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter where you are considering the tangent point to be:

Clock-wise rotation of a straight line is *always* positive by an accepted convention.

In any quadrant to obtain the inclination of tangent, we add $90^{\circ}$ to the inclination of the normal.

$$ \alpha _T = \alpha _N + \frac{\pi}{2} 
$$

$$ \tan(  \alpha _T-   \alpha _N )= \tan \pi/2 =
\frac{\tan \alpha _T-\tan \alpha _N}{1+\tan   \alpha _T\tan   \alpha _N }  $$

Denominator is zero, so  the slope of tangent is $$ \frac{dy}{dx}= \tan \alpha _T $$

Slope of normal is its negative reciprocal $$ -\frac{dx}{dy}= \tan \alpha _N $$

So in the image if tangent point to the circle is in first  quadrant then angle $ \alpha _T $ is $>\pi/2$ and angle $ ~\alpha _N $ is ${ <\pi/2 } $.

[image]

And if tangent point is in second  quadrant then angle $ \alpha _T $ is $>\pi$ and angle $ ~\alpha _N $ is ${ >\pi/2 } $.